# Adjusting TextBox contents with ScrollBar WPF

Tags: wpf, events, scrollbar

I am working out of the 3.5 .Net Framework.  I have a textbox next to a scroll bar in a stackpanel.  I would like it to be that when the user clicks the "up" arrow of the scrollbar, the contents of the textbox are incremented, and decremented when the click the "down" arrow of the scrollbar.  The problem is I am not sure which event I need to fire to do this.  I've tried MouseDown, MouseUp, PreviewMouseDown (which fires but I don't know how to differentiate whether the up or down arrow was clicked), PreviewMouseUp (same problem), StylusUp, StylusDown, PreviewStylusDown, PreviewStylusUp, StylusButtonDown, StylusButtonUp, and the previews for that also.  As I am debugging, I am using messageboxes to let me know I've entered that event, but none have shown (expcept for the PreviewMouseDown).  Being fairly new to WPF, I am basically baffled.

Does anyone know which event I should be looking for? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not abuse the ScrollBar for this but create a new control with two buttons.

Comment: Yea that was my back up plan. I was going for the numeric up/down control look that WinForms has.